# Undefined Node.js filepath

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, visual-studio-code

I'm a bit of a novice at JavaScript coding in the Visual Studio Code script editor.

I'm trying to read in a .txt file as an array.

Below is my code:

```
const fs = require('fs');

function readFile(filePath) {

    try {
        const data = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
        data.toString();
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(`Got an error trying to read the file: ${error.message}`);
    }

}

const input = readFile('G:/My Drive/Visual Studio Code/Advent of Code/2022/day05.txt');

console.log(input)
```

The text file is taken from the sample data found [here](https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/5). This is how it is in my text file in Visual Studio Code.

```
    [D]
[N] [C]
[Z] [M] [P]
 1   2   3

move 1 from 2 to 1
move 3 from 1 to 3
move 2 from 2 to 1
move 1 from 1 to 2
```

When I run the script, I get the below message in the *output* window. I don't understand why getting an **undefined** message for my *.js* file. It was working fine earlier. I didn't make any changes to the script, but I'm getting this message now.

[image]

FYI, the *.js* and *.txt* files are saved in my [Google Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Drive), but I don't see how that could be the problem. The **undefine** message only appears when I add the **console.log()** code.

Comment: Repalce data.toString() with return data.toString() should fix it for you

Comment: Oh my goodness, that solved it, @HarryHsu!! Thank you for your help on this :)
I don't know how to mark your comment as the correct solution.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77579169/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input you receive is just a Function Object, you need to return the value that fs can read.
Follow below:

```
function readFile(filePath) {

    try {
        const data = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
        return data.toString();        
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(`Got an error trying to read the file: ${error.message}`);
    }
}
```